# Access ng-repeat ng-form outside of the repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a button and a table. I want to disable the button if any of the rows are invalid. How do I achieve this?

```
///// This doesn't work, I have no access to myForm /////
<button ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Save</button>

<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in items" ng-form="myForm">
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="description" value="{{value.description}}" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### EDIT: Wrapping the entire table in a form, results in the following: http://pasteboard.co/FJccNeg.png

Comment: try wrapping this table into the form tag giving it a name `myForm`

Comment: You want to have a form for each row?

Comment: Please see the result of this here: http://pasteboard.co/FJccNeg.png
If one field is invalid, all of the fields become invalid.

Comment: @zeroflagL I don't really care, I just want the top button to be disabled if ANY of the fields in the table are invalid :-)

Comment: what exactly is the problem with wrapping your table inside a form? can't tell from the image

Comment: All of the fields that share the same name will be invalid if one of them is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need multiple things :

- Having a form tag in order to enable validation. Use novalidate attribute to disable broswer default validation
- Use only one name for each input, for this we will use the $index provided by ng-repeat in order to have each input having it's own validation
- add somewhat something that can trigger an error of validation in the sample below i added the required attribute. So as long as at least one field will be empty, the button will be disabled;

```js
angular.module("app", []).controller("ctrl", function($scope){
    $scope.items=[{description:"toto"},{}];//on with already existing one with empty
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app"> 
    <form name="myForm" ng-controller="ctrl" novalidate><!-- mandatory -->
    <button ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Save</button>
    
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in items" ng-form="myForm">
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="{{'description'+$index}}" ng-model="item.description" required/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Just want to point out that the button does not need to be inside the form.

Comment: welll true as long as the form is within the controller scope, but i'd rather having it inside.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! How do I refer to the fields in my ng-class? Like this: coefficientsForm.StartDate[$index].$invalid?

Comment: @RobinClaes if you do like i did it will be : `coefficientsForm['StartDate'+$index].$invalid`. Note that there is no point between coefficientsForm and the bracket.

Comment: @RobinClaes a last point : if you put the button outside the form, be sure to initialise the coefficientsForm in yur controller like this : `$scope.coefficientsForm = null` this wil ensure that your form validation data will be stored in that scope and not into an intermediary scope from where your button won't have access.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what you are doing with a form for each row, but in order to deactivate a button when a form is invalid, you have to wrap the button inside the form:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input name="description" type="text" ng-model="description" required />
  <button ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Save</button>
</form>
```

> If you cannot place your button inside this form, well, then you
>   cannot use the Angular magic so it doesn't make much sense using it
>   just half-ass.

Have an array of input ng-models inside your controller and check whether all are valid or not, and then set a a value true/false to deactivate your button.

Comment: Fair enough, but that's exactly the opposite of what my UX designer wants. We want a topbar button that globally saves the entire table.

Comment: Your UX Designer wants an Angular form and a ng-button somwhere? Don't confuse design with lack of knowledge or wrong use of frameworks.

Comment: @RobinClaes so you down vote for which reason? You don't like the answer?

Comment: Nope i'm the one that has downvoted because it totally forget the more important part about having multiple inputs validation separated within a ng-repeat. Furthermore i was pointed in the comment of my answer that the button can work outside of the form. However this may be tricky if there is some intermediate layer with their own scope like `ngIf`

Comment: Because this isn't the answer I'm looking for! Sorry

Answer (score -1):

First of all you should define a form with name parameter then create input field with name paramaeter too. Then you can reach input's error with form-name and input-name parameters.

```
    <form name="myForm" ng-controller="FormController" class="my-form">
          userType: <input name="input" ng-model="userType" required>
          <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">Required!</span><br> > 

         <button ng-disabled="myForm.input.$error.required>"
        </form>
```